# Adding a button to a <g> element using d3

Tags: javascript, button, d3.js

I was wondering what was the best way to go about adding a button to my group elements using d3.

I have currently built my visual using d3 to look something like:

```
<div>
  <svg>
    <g>
      <rect>
    </g>
    <g>...</g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

So I am wondering how I would add a clickable button in each group element. Some ideas I had were:

```
g.append("a")
  .append("image")
  .attr("src", ...);
```

or

```
g.append("a")
  .append("rect")
  .attr(...)
```

Ultimately I would like the button to perform an onclick event. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: If you want an actual button you'll have to use a `foreignObject` and embed HTML.

Comment: In the end I mainly just needed a clickable element, however thank you for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `rect` and use d3's [selection.on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on) api to register a click listener:

```js
var rect = d3.select('svg g rect');

rect.on('click', function() {
  console.log('i was clicked');
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 3.5em !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <rect height="100" width="200" fill="red"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I essentially ended up using this, except with an image tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Button isn't an SVG component, you can draw a rect or a circle(usually called legend) instead, and binding the click event on the legend.

You can refer to [grouped bars with legend click event](http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBar.html)